# Древний или древлий?

Tags: словообразование, этимология, старая-грамматика

Встретилось слово "древЛеправославный". Это старый вариант слова "древний" или совершенно другое слово?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слово **древний** в ст.-слав. языке писалось древ**л**ьнь, древьнь. В современном языке Л сохранилось в слове *издрев**л**е* - 'с древних времён, исстари'.

Слова **древний** и **дерево** имеют общие корни. Только **дерево** - общеслав., а **древний** - и.-е. по происхождению, но оба слова восходят к одному корневому гнезду. Есть интересная информация на этот счет в Историко-этимологическом словаре П.Я.Черных. Но словарная статья ("Древний") большая, привести ее здесь нет возможности.

Comment: Издревле - да, пожалуй. Но как могло ль выпасть в "древльнь" что-то недогоняю.

Comment: Если прослеживать связь с деревом, то, например, в белорусском языке есть слово драўЛяны - 'деревянный'.

Comment: Я не об этом. -ль здесь притяжательный суффикс. Может он быть привязан к "деревности" с последёющей пропажей? что-то сомневаюсь...

Ль - ещё может быть рефлексом древнего йота, но тогда уж точно деревянный - древ+ян... < древ+лян... Древность опять-таки не вписывается. надо бы ещё посмотреть, не родственно ли древо древности... Т.е. то, что оно родственно, это понятно, но на каком уровне... Не знаю, короче. Древляне-то уж явно деревянные были, не древние...

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего это какое-то закреплённое историей недоразумение.
Так называют себя и свою веру некоторые страрообрядцы.
Причины мне не совсем ясны.

Корень "древль" возможен, но он распадается на древ - дерево и -ль - притяжательный суффикс. Т.е значение - древесный. Это скорее о друидах, при чем тут провославие?